# Black holes as Quantum Computers

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I have been hearing lately that Black holes could be Quantum Computers or that some processes in a black hole simulate the operation of Quantum Computers. This is not my field of study, but I am looking to explore the subject in more detail. Any reading materials in the area that you can share with me would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're reacting to reactions to this paper: [arXiv:2301.09575](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.09575). It doesn't seem to require math beyond algebra or any practical facility with relativity, statistical mechanics, or quantum computing beyond willingness to look up some terminology.

I may be being ignorant here, but the paper seems to me to require a great deal of wishful thinking and general credulity.

The gist of the argument appears to be:

Microscopic black holes have more information per unit mass than matter and take up much less space. That information comes back out of them quickly if they are small. Therefore a civilization with no constraints would use arrays of microscopic black holes instead of arrays of bits of matter to "store"$^1$ large amounts of information and and "retrieve"$^2$ it quickly. Such tiny black holes are expected to be very hot, bright, and short-lived if Hawking radiation is an accurate model, and we can predict their characteristic radiation. Therefore we should keep an eye out for that characteristic radiation if we're reading data for signs of ET.

1: If by "store" you mean "not store at all actually". No mechanism is proposed for how to *not* get the information blasted violently back out at you as the unstable microscopic black hole spontaneously decays into all that bright, hot Hawking radiation. How could this possibly be useful, even if you could capture and decode all of that energy? No idea.

2: If by "retrieve" you mean "get blasted instantly by all the information and its associated energy with no delay, indexing, or search mechanism". How could this possibly be useful? No idea.

Why would ET go to all that trouble to build a collector for all that expensively produced light to decode it for its information content... which they had to start with a second before they turned it into a black hole and got back unchanged a second later at literally astronomical energy expense... and then throw away all the Gibbs free energy associated with its high temperature by letting it radiate out freely into cold space without putting a thermodynamic engine in between to extract work, such that we would only see dim diffuse infrared, not hot bright hot very high energy gamma? No idea.